# Serve and Deploy from different folders

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

My firebase project needs to be transpiled before it can be deployed. The code is written in `./app` and transpiled into `./dist`.

Currently when I run `firebase serve --only app` I get an error: "Cannot understand what targets to deploy. Check that you specified valid targets if you used the --only or --except flag. Otherwise, check your firebase.json to ensure that your project is initialized for the desired features."

Right now I've resorted to switching app to dist in package.json everytime I want to deploy and back when I'm in development. How should I configure my firebase.json so that I can serve from `./app` and deploy from `./dist`?

```js
//firebase.json
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint"
    ],
    "source": "app"
  }
}
```

```js
//package.json
{
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only dist",
    "lint": "eslint app test",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "precommit": "npm run lint && npm test",
    "prepare": "rm -rf dist && babel ./app/ -d ./dist && mkdir dist/private && cp app/private/conf.json dist/private/conf.json && cp package.json dist/package.json",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only app",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "cross-fetch": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jest": "^23.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: You can't make up new deploy targets, such as `app` or `dist`.  It has to be one of `hosting`, `functions`, `database`, `storage`, or `firestore`.  What happens when you choose one of those depends on its config in `firebase.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Unexpectedly I got the same error on my workstation. Sometimes the active project of the firebase cli is not properly update. The solution I found to pass this issue is to set the active project to another project then I undo it by setting the project I really want to use as the firebase active project.

```
firebase use antotherFirebaseProjectID
```

then

```
firebase use myFirebaseProjectID
```

Otherwise you can also try to restart your computer and hope it will initialize the firebase active project properly